# Find the last folder named as month from subfolders

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

I have reports grouped by months in folder tree

> "somepath\YYYY\MMMYYYY"

For example `"somepath\2017\MAR2017"`.
Obviously, there may be up to 12 folders `"MMMYYYY"` in the Year folder.
System uploads files from the last folder identified by month in its name. I.e. among folders Jan2017, Feb2017, Mar2017 it should upload files from Mar2017.

I tried convert the foldername to number:

```
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim ObjFolder : Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("somepath\2017\")
Set fc = ObjFolder.SubFolders 'here I should get all folders with months in their names
For each f in fc
a = Month("01-"&left(f.name, 3)&"-"&right(f.name, 4))
print a
Next
```

it prints next:

> 4
>
> 2
>
> 3

Next step should be identifying the greatest number from these and set working folder name as

```
a = MonthName(maxnumber)&"2017"
workingfolder = "somepath\2017\"&a&"\"
```

How to identify that max number or max month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

```
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim ObjFolder : Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("somepath\2017\")
Set fc = ObjFolder.SubFolders
    For i=0 to fc.count
        For each f in fc
            a = Month("01-"&left(f.name, 3)&"-"&right(f.name, 4))
            Redim Preserve arr(fc.count)
            arr(i)=a
        Next
    Next
    arrLen = UBound(arr) 'Find the length of array
    For j= 0 to arrLen
     If arr(j) > max Then
        max=arr(j)
     End If
    Next
Dim OrgFolder : Set OrgFolder = fso.GetFolder(ObjFolder&"\"&MonthName(arr(0), True)&"2017\")
```